# Mean along 4th dimension of 4-D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, mean

I have 3-D spectrograms (5x3x129) per subject. I have 25 subjects.

So I want to know what the average spectrogram would be - so result should be 5x3x129

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In what language have you this matrix? Is this R? Could  you copy some sample data, and how you expect it to be at the end?

Comment: Hi, I use Matlab.Basically I have 3-D spectrograms (5x3x129) per subject. I have 25 subjects. So I want to know what the average spectrogram would be - so result should be 5x3x129

Comment: A sample would be useful, please read [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I add the information from the comment to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 4D array of size 5 x 3 x 129 x 25, in which each of the spectrograms is one slice in the fourth dimension, use

```
mean(array,4)
```

where `array` is your 4D array. The second argument, `4` in this case, specifies along which dimension to take the mean.